# Use C# and Xamarin to count rotations of a wheel

Tags: c#, xamarin, rotation

I'm wrestling with Xamarin and am trying to find out how to count rotations of a phone (or similar device) that will be affixed to the inside of a truck tire and pushed down a track.  I've had some luck with Quaternions and Euler angles when it comes to getting device angles but I'm stymied as to how to count rotations of a wheel. Has anybody out there had any experience with this sort of thing? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure if phone gyroscope could do so? If wheel revolving fast enough won't centrifugal force overcome any other?

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The wheel will be turning pretty slowly and I am getting some quaternions and euler angle output.  I'm going to put the phone on some sort of axis, turn it and see what I get out of that.  Stumbling forward.....it would be nice (but unlikely) to find someone who's done the exact same thing. 